# Unable to get a selected foreign key value from dropdown in controller mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables `Customer` and `Status`

CustomerController.cs

```
// GET: Customers/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            P  var Query = from d in db.Status
                        orderby d.Name
                                   select d;
            ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(Query, "myStatusId", "Name", selected);
            return View();
        }
```

Create.cshtml

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.status, ViewBag.Status as SelectList, String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.status)
        </div>
```

> Now I'm able to get all Status in `Customer/Create.cshtml` page My
>   Issue is when I select any status from dropdown and click on create i
>   dont get any status value in my customer object it is NULL

having following exception 
`{"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Status' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}`

CustomerController.cs

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
```

Model Classes
MyIdClass.cs

```
public class MyIdClass
    {

        private Guid myIDField;


        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid myID
        {
            get { return myIDField; }
            set { myIDField = value; }
        }

    }
```

Customer.cs

```
public partial class Customer : MyIdClass
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}

        private Status statusField;

          public Status status
        {
            get
            {
                return this.statusField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.statusField = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Status .cs

```
 public partial class Status : MyIdClass {
         private string nameField;

  public string name {
            get {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

 }
```

Comment: You need to show your model (but clearly your property `status` is not typeof `string`)

Comment: I'm excepting full Status object here .. updating models

Comment: A `<select>` posts back a single value (the value of the selected option which in your case is the value of `myStatusId`). You cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object.

Comment: updated model classes

Comment: Do this correctly and use a view model (say) `CustomerVM` with properties `int SelectedStatus` and `SelectList StatusList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have a `StatusId` field in your `Customer`, If you except `StatusId` you need to call `Html.DropDownListFor` for the `ForeignKey` column property of your `Customer` instead of the whole `ForeignKey` object property:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StatusId, ViewBag.Status as SelectList, String.Empty)
```

But if you don't have such property and you excpect `Status`, then you can use it this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.status.myStatusId, ViewBag.Status as SelectList, String.Empty)

@*/
If you need the value of model.status.Name 
You can set it using a simple script on the dropdown change, 
otherwise, you don't need to use a hiddenfor
*@
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.status.Name)
```

Then in a `Post` it should initialize your `customer.Status` property with values.

**Note**

Using a `ViewModel` that contains `int StatusId` is a more clean way as  mentioned by [`Stephen Muecke`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) too in comments.